# why I can't malloc memory after simply opendir

Tags: c, malloc

My env is:

> system:ubuntu 18.04
>
> gcc version 7.5.0
>
> memory:
>
> KiB Mem :  7930352 total,  5953392 free,  1241908 used,   735052 buff/cache
>
> KiB Swap:  5169144 total,  5169144 free,        0 used.  6419340 avail Mem

The fpp always gets NULL point, there is the code below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <dirent.h>

int main(void)
{
    DIR *dirp;
    char** fpp=NULL;
    const char* basePath="/tmp/temp";

    if ((dirp=opendir(basePath)) == NULL)
    {
        perror("Open dir error...");
        exit(1);
    }

    fpp = (char**)malloc(8);

    if (NULL == fpp);
    {
        printf("error,no mem for fpp\r\n");
    }
    
    if (NULL != fpp)
    {
        free(fpp);
        fpp=NULL;
    }

    if (NULL != dirp)
        closedir(dirp);
 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There is only one file in /tmp/temp dir

Comment: There is a stray `;` after the `if` condition

Comment: Also, why use `printf("error,no mem for fpp\r\n");` instead of `perror` like you did earlier?

Comment: yes,using perror is a good style.

Answer (score 2):

You have

```
if (NULL == fpp);
{
    printf("error,no mem for fpp\r\n");
}
```

which is equivalent to

```
if (NULL == fpp)
{
}

{
    printf("error,no mem for fpp\r\n");
}
```

Remove the extraneous semi-colon.

Comment: OK,I make a stupid mistake.

Comment: It happens :) . . .